# Does "Script App" from google sheets do auto login in websites?

Tags: javascript, java, google-sheets

I'm trying to make this work in google sheets Script App but not sure how to use `getElementById`

Website

```
    <div id="loginusr">
      <input type="text" value="" class="use inputCss" placeholder="Digite o nome do usuário">
    <div id="loginpow">
      <input type="password" value class="pow inputCss" placeholder="Por favor, digite sua senha">

    <div id="loginbtn" class="hover">Login</div>
```

My Code

```
    function test(){

      var url = 'https://www.renovigi.solar/';

      var html = "<script>window.open('" + url + "');google.script.host.close()</script>";

      var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);

      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Opening website');


    }
```

I have tried to add `document.getElementById("loginusr").Value = "TEST"` but then I get the message

> ReferenceError: "document" is not defined."

Answer (score 0):

### `document.getElementById` is a client-side method - you cannot user it in the server-side Apps Script code part

You can use it inside of the javascript part of your code (within the `<script>` tags).

However, think about what this method is supposed to do - do you want to access an element from your website? In this case you need to embed the full code of your website with an `html` file of your Apps Script project and create a https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web in order to consolidate the server and client-sides of your code.

Also: It should be [`document.getElementById("loginusr").value`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp), not `document.getElementById("loginusr").Value`